# Copying files to User Profile

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am working on Microsoft Teams package and MSI is installing the files in Profiles Files x86 and I want to copy these files to the user profile. This is a per machine installation.

```
# Installing Teams 1.3.12058

$Parms=' /I Teams_windows_x64.msi ALLUSER=1 ALLUSERS=1 /qn
$CMDS= "msiexec.exe"
LogWrite "Executing $CMDS $Parms"
$Proces=Start-Process $CMDS $Parms -PassThru -Wait -WorkingDirectory $InstDir
$Extval=$Proces.ExitCode 
LogWrite "Installed Teams 1.3  exit code:$Extval"


#  Copying files and folders from "C:\program files X86" to User profile

$userFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users' -Exclude 'Default*','All Users','Administrator', 'Public' | Select -ExpandProperty FullName

foreach ($uf in $userFolder) 

$Dest = "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Microsoft"
$Source = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\"

{
Copy-Item -LiteralPath "$Source" -Destination $Dest -Force -Recurse
}
```

It's throwing  an error at the copy-item command. Can someone kindly help me on this one.

Answer (score 2):

foreach loop is not closed properley. kindly close it and excute again

foreach ($uf in $userFolder)
{

$Dest = "C:\Users$user\AppData\Local\Microsoft"
$Source = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft"

{
Copy-Item -LiteralPath "$Source" -Destination $Dest -Force -Recurse
}}